# Determine $\bigcup_{x\in I} A_{x}$ and $\bigcap_{x\in I} A_{x}$ and prove it

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $I=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 < x < 1\}$. For each $x \in I$ the set $A_{x}$ is given by
$$A_{x} = \{y \in \mathbb{R} \mid -\frac{1}{x} \leq y < x\}.$$ Determine $\bigcup_{x\in I} A_{x}$ and $\bigcap_{x\in I} A_{x}$ and prove it

Normally I would give a attempt on an exercise when I ask a question, but I just don't even know how I'm supposed to start, I searched a book for a similar question, I kind of found one but I couldn't apply anything they used there. If someone could still help me.

Well the only thing I could say is that I believe $\bigcup_{x\in I} A_{x} \to (-\infty, 1)$ not sure about the other one

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes my bad, I'm changing it right now, thanks it should be -1/x

Answer (score 1):

For $\bigcup_{x \in I}A_x$ you already conjectured that it is equal to $(-\infty,1)$. Now, in order to prove this, you only need to show two things:

- For every $y \in (-\infty,1)$ there exists an $x \in I$ with $y \in A_x$.
- For every $y \geq 1$ you have $y \notin A_x$ for every $x \in I$.

For $\bigcap_{x \in I}A_x$ I would suggest to compute $A_x$ for some sample values of $x \in I$ (maybe something close to $0$, something close to $1$, something in the middle). Then, you can again form a conjecture on what $\bigcap_{x \in I}A_x$ could be. Then, in order to show your conjecture $\bigcap_{x \in I}A_x=B$ you have to show the following two things:

- For every $y \in B$ and every $x \in I$ you have $y \in A_x$.
- For every $y \notin B$ there exists some $x \in I$ with $y \notin A_x$.

Comment: Okay thank you I'll try this